# Is there a (playable) helicopter in Donald Duck: Goin' Quackers?

Tags: donald-duck-goin-quackers

In one of the tutorial messages, Gyro Gearloose tells about a (heli)copter, something along the lines of "Gyrocopter is also available". I've assumed that the helicopter is an unlockable item in the game, but does the vehicle actually exist and does it have any gameplay purpose?
I've played the PC version and I don't know if there are *major* [version differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Duck:_Goin%27_Quackers#Version_differences). [Donald Duck: Goin' Quackers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Duck:_Goin'_Quackers) is known as Donald Duck: Quack Attack in Europe.

Comment: When sourcing information online, helicopter/copter can easily be confused with floating platforms held by a rotor which appear on the Duckie Mountain levels.

Comment: I will post a screenshot of the Gyro Gearloose's statement once I find the line.